# Handle when the user tries to write something directly on a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pivot-table

What trigger can I use to handle the message below (that comes up when a user tries to write something in a Pivot Table) by opening a form?

[image]

My idea would be that the user would try to write something in a pivot table, and a form would pop-up with more meaningful information, a textbox would activate so they can write in the textbox and update the source of the Pivot Table. But I have not found a compatible trigger.

The only workaround for now would be for the form to popup on cell select, but sometimes you just want to click around the values, without actually having a form pop-up each time.

Comment: You have a people problem, not a technical problem. Trying to solve a people problem with a technical solution is a never-ending quest usually doomed to failure. Explain to users how this works. Give them some training. Write them a manual.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the source data but not the PivotTable data.